# Create a node on user account creation. Display link to user on first login

Tags: panels

I need to capture addtional private information about a users company
when they register (one time).

What i am currently doing.

1. Creating new node on account creation with rules.
2. Add a view that filters by node author, and display it on the users profile, with a edit link.
3. The user can then edit the node that he is the author to on his profile page.

This works

I want to display a link or auto redirect to the node once the user has logged in for the first time.

Been busy with this for a long time. Any advice or Pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Field collection](https://drupal.org/project/Field_Collection) I was able to add fields within a field to collect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7, I'd advice you **not** to do this.

Drupal users are now *entities* and field-able.

In **Admin > Configuration > People > Manage Fields** tab, you can add new fields to the profile. With [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module, you can have even more control over these fields (this will become a new entity type, with option to have separate tab in user edit page, etc).

If you are using Drupal 6, while being prepared to upgrade your site to Drupal 7 or 8 in near future, you can use [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module to do this.

Also, if you need to automate these data/fields with user registration, give a try to [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Profile2 and Content Profile, as well as core profiles have Views support so you can show these profile fields in user with a 1:1 relationship (if you create a new node without binding it to the user, how do you find the correct node from pool ?).

Comment: I'm using a relationships content:author to get the correct node. 

I've tried both the "profile fields" and "profile 2", it also works, I ran into a few issues while testing diffrent solutions though.

Comment: Going to try Entityforms next